# Passing array from one android activity to another and using it in a spinner

Tags: java, android, arrays

In my source code, I have two activities. In activity A.java I have an array

```
private String[] typeName = new String[100];
```

and I am also starting a new activity

```
    public void LoadCueCardSet(View view){

    Intent loadCueCardPage = new Intent(this, LoadCueCardSet.class);
    loadCueCardPage.putExtra("types", typeName);
    startActivity(loadCueCardPage);
}
```

In the second activity, I have

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_load_cue_card_set);
    // Array of choices


// Selection of the spinner
    Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);

// Application of the Array to the Spinner

    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    String colors[] = extras.getStringArray("types"); // doesn't work

    ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,   android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, colors);
    spinnerArrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item); // The drop down view
    spinner.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter);
```

I know the problem is with the spinner and it has to do with the array I am passing it, but the problem is that it should work because I tried this with a an actual array created in the second activity. This code below works if I don't use an array passed from another activity.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_load_cue_card_set);
    // Array of choices


// Selection of the spinner
    Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);

// Application of the Array to the Spinner

    String colors[] = {"red"}; //works

    ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,   android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, colors);
    spinnerArrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item); // The drop down view
    spinner.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter);
```

Comment: Did you mean `getStringArrayExtra`?

Comment: I tried String colors[] = getIntent().getStringArrayExtra("types"); , but it still crashes.

Comment: Are all 100 indices in the array populated?

Comment: Nope, and I recently had a suspicion this was the problem as well, since it's garbage values if all the indices are not populated.